# VPN Connections & Tray Icons in Juno

Tags: wingpanel, release-juno, vpn

I installed Juno yesterday.

---

**VPN Connections** in Network setting do not affect on the browsers and in Chrome proxy settings is written:

*"When running Google Chrome under a supported desktop environment, the system proxy settings will be used. However, either your system is not supported or there was a problem launching your system configuration.
But you can still configure via the command line. Please see man google-chrome-stable for more information on flags and environment variables."*

, but they affect the whole system through the terminal.

---

**Software icons** are not visible in the system tray.

Answer (score 0):

About notificacion icons. Juno dropped the support of the old ayatana

While the software devs implement the new way you can have them back by...

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yunnxx/elementary
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install indicator-application wingpanel-indicator-ayatana
```

then you need to edit a file (i used nano, use any editor you want - avoiding a holy war)

```
$ sudo nano /etc/xdg/autostart/indicator-application.desktop
```

find the line

```
OnlyShowIn=Unity;GNOME;
```

and add Pantheon

```
OnlyShowIn=Unity;GNOME;Pantheon;
```

that's it, just restart X and you will have the old notification area icons

Answer (score 0):

Juno doesn't come with system tray.

It's a shame, but you can install it in a much smooth way.

I find out a marvelous github repo. https://github.com/mdh34/elementary-indicators

**Tools to use:**

- Eddy (from AppCenter)

**Steps**

- Download .deb file 'indicator-application', a package to support Pantheon. [link](https://github.com/mdh34/elementary-indicators/releases)
- Download .deb file 'wingpanel-indicator-ayatana', a package that used to be in olders distro. [link](https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/ubuntu/stable/+files/wingpanel-indicator-ayatana_2.0.3+r27+pkg17~ubuntu0.4.1.1_amd64.deb)

Once both packages installed, reboot and have fun.