# VPN Unlimited- minimise to Wingpanel?

Tags: wingpanel, vpn

I have paid for a lifetime subscription to VPN Unlimited, so would like to use it on my Elementary notebook computer. Unfortunately, while it does appear to run correctly, I can't get it to do so in any mode other than w/its program window displaying. Yes, I know, I can move it to another desktop. But, under Windows (and other linuxes), you can close VPN Unlimited's main window and the program will minimise to the notification area.

I Googled a bit, and found the page below, but doing as directed did not solve the issue. Any idea of what I can do to get VPN Unlimited to minimise to Wingpanel?

[VPN Connections & Tray Icons in Juno](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16877/vpn-connections-tray-icons-in-juno)

Thanks,
-Z

Answer (score 1):

That's most likely because for better or worse, Elementary/Pantheon defaults to hiding indicators that haven't been whitelisted.

You can correct this issue, and get indicator functionality back in general [by following these instructions on GitHub](https://github.com/mdh34/elementary-indicators). Basically install [this package](https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/ubuntu/stable/+files/wingpanel-indicator-ayatana_2.0.3+r27+pkg17~ubuntu0.4.1.1_amd64.deb) and then reboot.